# How do I dispatch actions in redux, to requests received from websockets when page is loaded?

Tags: reactjs, websocket, react-router, redux, react-redux

I am using Redux with react but have come across a problem. In my app I listen to messages from BE via websockets. When the app is loaded, then it should listen to the websocket messages sent and dispatch some actions.

How do I do that ?

Answer (score 2):

You can start listening to web socket events when your component loads. Pass the `dispatch` method so you can dispatch actions once there is data.

```
@connect(state => ({}))
class MainComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    socket.onmessage = (e) => {
      this.props.dispatch({ type: 'SOCKET_DATA', payload: e.data });
    };
  }
}
```